# netCDF incorrect format for lat long

Tags: python, arcmap, netcdf

I am trying to display a netCDF file that I obtained from NOAA in ArcMap. However, it keeps crashing ArcMap. I have used precipitation netCDFs from NWS before with no issues.

The netCDF is just a sample they sent me of many netCDF files they will start making available as part of a new lightning data release. So I would like to write a script that corrects the netCDF files.

They told me there are "some issues with data formatting (e.g., unsigned integers for event lat and lon) and that it won't be fixed for some time."

I used the following code to open the netCDF to look at the data. I only included the coordinates output and not the data variables and attributes.

```
xr.open_dataset('C:\\lightning\\sample.nc'

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                                 (number_of_events: 5879, 
number_of_field_of_view_bounds: 2, number_of_flashes: 687, number_of_groups: 
3454, number_of_time_bounds: 2, number_of_wavelength_bounds: 2)
Coordinates:
    event_id                                (number_of_events) int32 -940849349 ...
    event_time_offset                       (number_of_events) datetime64[ns] 2017-09-08T19:30:19.917000 ...
    event_lat                               (number_of_events) float64 -1.687 ...
    event_lon                               (number_of_events) float64 -188.5 ...
    event_parent_group_id                   (number_of_events) int32 1324574251 ...
    group_id                                (number_of_groups) int32 1324574251 ...
    group_time_offset                       (number_of_groups) datetime64[ns] 2017-09-08T19:30:19.834000 ...
    group_lat                               (number_of_groups) float32 -1.68695 ...
    group_lon                               (number_of_groups) float32 -55.3391 ...
    group_parent_flash_id                   (number_of_groups) int16 12590 ...
    flash_id                                (number_of_flashes) int16 12590 ...
    flash_time_offset_of_first_event        (number_of_flashes) datetime64[ns] 2017-09-08T19:30:19.834000 ...
    flash_time_offset_of_last_event         (number_of_flashes) datetime64[ns] 2017-09-08T19:30:19.834000 ...
    flash_lat                               (number_of_flashes) float32 -1.68695 ...
    flash_lon                               (number_of_flashes) float32 -55.3391 ...
    product_time                            datetime64[ns] 2017-09-08T19:30:20
    lightning_wavelength                    float32 777.4
    group_time_threshold                    float32 0.0
    flash_time_threshold                    float32 3.33
    lat_field_of_view                       float32 0.0
    lon_field_of_view                       float32 -89.5
```

I then used np.savetxt to save *event_lat*, *event_lon*, *group_lat*, and *group_lon* to CSV files so I could ananlyze the coordinates.

What I found was that *group_lat* values ranged from 42 to -51 and *group_lon* values range from -44 to -142. These are correct because the file is supposed to display data from North and South America and parts of adjacent oceans.

But, *event_lat* values ranged from -0.03 to -133 and *event_lon* values ranged from -90.2 to -222.29. Looking at *event_lat* CSV, there is a chunk of data that ranged from -.03 to -51 (this should be data for southern hemisphere) and a chunk of data ranging from -90.5 to -132 (this should be the northern hemisphere data). However, that range should actually be 0.5 to 42 latitude.

I'm not sure what's going on with the *event_lon* data. -90 to -142 coordinates look similar between *event_lon* and *group_lon*, so I think that is fine. However, *event_lon* also has data ranging from -177 to -222 and no data greater than -90. The *group_lon* data ranges from -44 to -142.5.

Is there a way I can fix these files with python?

Comment: Is it GEOS data? A colleague has been working with another team to add support for geos data to ArcGIS...hopefully for Pro 2.1, 10

Comment: 10.6! Dratted android app.

Comment: No it's not. It's new data from the geostationary lightning mapper (GLM). http://www.goes-r.gov/spacesegment/glm.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant GOES. From what we've (Esri) found, coordinates are natively in radians in a quasi-projected coordinate system. That data needs to be georeferenced before it's usable in a lot of GIS software packages. The GLM data may be georeferenced already. I don't know.

Comment: It is WGS84 unprojected. I was able to run the Make NetCDF Feature Layer tool on the group_area variable without ArcMap crashing in a new mxd. However, it only plots one point. Going to data frame properties I can see WGS_1984 as the current coord system. If I try to use other variables to make NetCDF Feature Layer, ArcMap will crash.

Comment: Are you saying the `event_lat` could be corrected by an arithmetic transform?  Like the NetCDF Operator ncap2 with something like  `ncap2 -s 'event_lat = event_lat < -90 ? 90.0-event_lat : event_lat' badfile.nc goodfile.nc`  ?  I frequently use `ncap2` for preprocessing.

Comment: Yes I believe so. I will take a look at ncap2. Also I took a closer look at event_lon and cannot figure out how it should be transformed to correct longitude coordinates. I have edited my question to include this info.

Comment: Is the ncap2 code for use with python? I am trying it while declaring the netcdf strings but it says invalid syntax every time.
    ncap2 -s 'event_lat = event_lat < -90 ? 90.0-event_lat : event_lat' incdf outcdf  where incdf = 'C:\\GLM\\sample.nc'